# Multiplayer Rules Considering Enchantments

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-two-headed-giant

Rule 810.5 about the Two-Headed Giant game variant says:

> 810.5. With the exception of life total and poison counters, a team’s resources (cards in hand, mana, 
>   and so on) are not shared in the Two-Headed Giant variant. Teammates may review each other’s 
>   hands and discuss strategies at any time.
>   **Teammates can’t manipulate each other’s cards or 
>   permanents**.

Now, my question is: Is it possible to enchant or target my teammates' permanents or does this rule forbid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That rule is using "manipulate" in the sense of "physically interact with". It's saying that you can't grab cards out of your teammate's hand or tap your teammate's permanents, for example. This does not prevent you from targeting or enchanting your teammate or their cards/permanents.

Comment: To be extra clear; you can only do so if the target is valid under normal rules... in other words, if an aura says "Enchant creature you control", then your teammate's creatures are not valid targets because teammate or not, you don't control them.

Comment: So in practice, the big things this stops are probably people trying to play for their teammates (not really the spirit of 2HG!), and maybe "stop touching my stuff" fights.